# Insert duplicate rows (based on one cell-value) in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I have this formula that copies rows (with data in col A) into a new range. Column A contains number indicating how many duplicates the row should yield in the result. Also the output rows gets sorted based on the value in column A.

```
=sort(arrayformula(vlookup(
                    transpose(split(query(rept(row(D2:D)&" ",A2:A),,9^9)," ")),
                    arrayformula({row(D2:D),{A2:A,D2:F}}),
                    {2,3,4,5},
                    0)),
  1,
  TRUE)
```

This is not exectly what I need thou. Instead of having a single value in the cells in column A that indicates how many times the row should be duplicated I need to have a text string like “2,3,5” in every cell in that column, where the individual numbers in the string indicates the position of the row in output (rather than the number of times the row should be copied).

For example, in the output I want the row with the string “2,3,5” to be copied three times. The output should have one of the rows be 2:nd from top, the other 3:rd from top, and the last one the 5:th from top.

If I could have the A2:A part of this range {A2:A,J2:N} instead contain the matching values for split(A2:A) I think it would do what I want.

This is a copy of my google sheet. Hopefully it's possible to understand what it is I'm trying to achieve.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sp5DRBwFP0-aG-FvjUPKBmyylz0WoPB63ASOOdUGdnI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've added it to the google-sheet now.

Comment: The leftmost column in the orange output range contains  the comma-separated values from using column C (which is what I want to do). Every row in input is copied to output as many times as there are comma-separated numbers in column C for that row. And then the output is sorted on those numbers, so that I can have the same row copied to multiple different positions in output.

Comment: The leftmost column in the output isn't really something I'm interested in seing in the final output. It's really only used for sorting. I left it in the sheet to make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: You are proposing to change the layout parameters to a comma-delimited format. I have a feeling that this creates a complication (not necessarily insurmountable, but unnecessary). You've not mentioned your motivation, but may I remind you that you can put your source data (including the layout parameters) on a different sheet to your output - this might enable you to simply the layout parameters. Second, though I wrote a script as an answer, I used a more explicit structure for the layout parameters which may (or not) be a useful alternative.

Comment: I intend to have the data (and the input parameters) on one sheet. And multiple sheets of output. One column of input parameters (in a string) for each of the sheets with output.

Comment: More power to you!

Comment: I deleted the "script" answer because it would have the effect of discouraging others from looking at your question - particularly since you want a formulaic approach.